# How do I move a file via the command line to the Google Drive storage server? (from GNOME Online Accounts)

Tags: command-line, gnome, google-drive

In another post it tells to use the direct path to the storage server as for example `google-drive://ahmet_yasar@gmx.de/`. But when I try to move a file to this path it can not find the path. Can you tell me the proper way?

Thanks

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/google-drive-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: rclone is also an option but initiated by cli only.  rclone has both a local cache mode and direct copy.